# Открытие сборки Android (AOSP) в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть необходимость подключиться к процессу в сборке Android O.
Пытаюсь это сделать через Android Studio 3.1 в Ubuntu.
Выполнял инструкции типа [такой](http://ronubo.blogspot.ru/2016/01/debugging-aosp-platform-code-with.html).

Проблемы начинаются во время индексации в самой Android Studio (после открытия проекта *.ipr). ~40 минут идет индексация. Потом, вроде как, проект полностью открылся, однако раз в 1.5 секунды опять появляется сообщение об индексации и снова пропадает. И так бесконечно. Само собой работать невозможно.

Сам Android собирается утилитой make без проблем. Плата прошивается и работает.
Я уже пробовал и увеличивать память для Android Studio. Что-то ничего не помогает.

В чем может быть причина? Может что-то "подкрутить" в Android Studio?

Comment: В общем пока победить Android Studio не получилось. Однако получилось с IntelliJ IDEA. Проделал такие же операции - получилось подключиться к процессу. Пока остановлюсь на IDEA